# Two green screens in FCPX?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, greenscreen, chromakey

I am a beginner FCPX user and am currently working on setting up a green screen studio for interviews/podcasts/etc. I am planning on painting a wall with this [paint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZX2V8S) and using a [this](https://wondermat.com/cart/index.html?prodwmr.html) for my floor mat (in the light green color option). I am planning on doing the keying in either FCPX or Motion, but I am unsure if it (they) will be able to handle to slightly different colors in the same chroma key frame. Is it possible to make the floor and wall, even though they are slightly different shades of green, into one seamless green screen in FCPX or Motion?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to have long shots of your talent?  Having them stand on green is going to make spill more of a problem.  I'm not saying don't go for it if you feel like you should.  I'm saying sticking to medium shots and closeups with a subject that is physically separated from everything green keys way better and easier, especially in fcpx, which doesn't have the best keyer. If you do go full body, use some soft magenta back light on your talent to reduce green spill.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, you can typically adjust a tolerance for the level of removal.  If the colors of green are closer than the next nearest color, you should be fine, if not, then you would have to do two keys, though I would expect you should be able to stack two layers to get the necessary transparency.  (Basically keying over a keyed image, since the result of a keyed image is a layer with alpha.)

Keep in mind that lighting will also be a significant concern and you could always paint the floor tiles as well to get the same color on everything.